# ACF pro - return day with date picker

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF pro for my wordpress.
My datepicker field is a repeater field.

I need to return only the day.

my code :

```
<?php   
if( have_rows('dates') ):
while ( have_rows('dates') ) : the_row();
echo get_sub_field('date')."</br>";
endwhile;
else :
echo __( 'No dates available.','mywebsite' );
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the return value of the date field.

[image]

> EDIT

Ok, so if you want to display two dates, one full and one is only day, you first need the return value to be the full date, for this example lets day it d/m/Y

```
$full_date = get_sub_field('date'); // the full date (format d/m/Y);
$day_from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $full_date)->format('d'); // will get the day from the $full_date
```

This will get you the result you need.

See [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for more information about the method

Comment: thank you.
but i have to display the both version. The first only the day and the second the complete date.

Comment: @microb14 Edited my answer, now you can get both full day and day from a single date field

Answer (score 0):

The get_sub_field() function would typically return a string depending on the field type. This instance it will return a timestamp as as string eg '2021-06-28 10:28:00'

If you want to return the day only you could use PHP's *strtotime* function which will then return you a datetime epoch integer - this can then be used in conjunction with php's *date* function to print as the day. Here is a list of the formats you can use for the *date* function : [PHP DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Example :

```
<?php   
if (have_rows('dates')):
  while (have_rows('dates')) : the_row();
    $dateTime = strtotime(get_sub_field('date'));
    echo("Day : " . date('l', $dateTime) . "</br>");
  endwhile;
else :
  echo __('No dates available.', 'mywebsite');
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. it displat always de same day.

Comment: Without knowing what the data is not sure what to suggest further - what does get_sub_field  return on each row? - is it a timestamp? as in your ACF field options you can choose what format you would like it returned in. I normally use 'c' to return a timestamp with timezone, but the default may be different - You could change it there - eg on your field settings set your return format to be 'l' to get the full day name or 'D' to get the shorterned day or 'j' to get the day of the month. - My example is assuming you're returning something that 'strtotime' can interpret

Answer (score 0):

As another solution which is within your setup rather than your code - change the 'Return Format' of the actual field.

See : [ACF Date Time Picker Docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/)

Examples would be :

- 'd' - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
- 'j' - Day of the month without leading zeros
- 'D' - A textual representation of a day, three letters
- 'l' - A full textual representation of the day of the week

Then your original code will output the correct format :

```
<?php   
if( have_rows('dates') ):
  while ( have_rows('dates') ) : 
    the_row();
    echo('Day: ' .  get_sub_field('date') . "</br>"); //This will now output your 'Return Format' in ACF setup
  endwhile;
else :
  echo __( 'No dates available.','mywebsite' );
endif;
?>
```